# Entire site redirect with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We currently move our site from asp to php keeping the same domain .
So i am bit confused about the redirects of product pages

OLD site product page: examplesite.com/Product.asp?ID=old_ID

NEW site product page: examplesite.com/product/new_ID/product_description

old_ID and new_ID have no similarity

1) So i found the way (from a stack similar question )for redirecting a single page

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ID=old_id(&|$) [NC]
rewriterule ^/?Product\.asp         /product/new_ID/product_description[r=301,L,nc]
```

I am currently using this code to redirect ~2000 products . Problem htaccess is getting too big . I haven't tested perfomance times but I assume they will be affected, right? Is there a better way to be done?

2) Some product IDs may link to the same page in the new site 
ie. 
examplesite.com/Product.asp?ID=old_same_ID1

examplesite.com/Product.asp?ID=old_same_ID2

Both link to same page.
Is there a way two combine the RewriteCond in order to cut down htaccess file size?

Comment: Here is your first problem - your old url doesn't include 'product_description', so you can't make your new urls without that. You could do this with new url: /product/new_id/ , all with a simple .htaccess rule, this will work for zillion of products.

Comment: Maybe i was not clear enough. Old ID and New ID have no similarity and are no linked in any way (db). We have a complete set of new product IDs. So i don't think that product description is any kind of problem

Comment: Add your old_ID in your new database. And after you can redirecting in a single page from old to new ID with product description.

Comment: If ids arent the same, and descriptions arent there, dont use .htaccess for each product. In htaccess redirect all requests to a central script, from there parse url and redirect to the needed page using header()

Comment: That's what I did and I think is the best solution for it. Entered the ID mapping in database and added a single rule in htaccess. Thanks guys